# Debugging Android Apps without USB or root

Tags: android, logging, usb

I'm currently developing a small android app which communicates with a FTDI chip over USB so I can't use logcat to get the logs live. Unfortunatly the Android device is a Galaxy Tab 2 with Android 4.1.2 which I'm not allowed to root. That means adb-wireless won't work too. And because it's just a small app setting up a bugtracker system like ACRA seems a bit oversized.

Is there another way to get the logs of my app?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't think of any "live" logcat output, but you can view your Logcat Output (which is Buffered) via `adb logcat`. Test the things in your app you want to do or to get the Error you try to solve, then connect the USB to a Computer running adb and dump the Log.

More information for the `logcat` Command can be found [here](http://www.herongyang.com/Android/Debug-adb-logcat-Command-Option-Log-Buffer.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can make a utility function that opens an HTTP connection and writes to a web server.
This adds a little overhead to your application, but works fine to get log info.
Easy to implement, no rooting required!

Or you could write a little service that runs a web server that responds to requests with a dump on logcat (or a tail or logcat or something).

It might even be possible to write a shell script that uses curl or wget to do this (that is  send get requests to a webserver in order to pass logcat output), but you might need to install them, which in turn you might need root for, so... maybe this wouldn't meet your needs.

I guess it might even be possible to create a network share on your workstation, mount it on your android device and just redirect logcat output to a file on the share. But I didn't try it - let me know if you do!

Answer (score 1):

You could use apps like [Logcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat) or others alike, which will give you the same output as your IDE Logcat console. 
You can turn on the logging, do your stuff in your app, and return to the logcat app to check out the log, mail it to yourself etc.

Comment: I'm developing on a tablet from my company which isn't rooted but unfortunatly that's necessary since Jelly Bean.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, had no idea that these apps need root since 4.1 :s

Answer (score 0):

I did a little bit more research and it seems that there's no possibility to read the logs easily without having root rights. You're able to read the logcat output using bugtracking libraries like ACRA in your Android app, but it's a lot more effort to include them and analyze the logs.

I'm going to develop on my own (rooted) tablet with adb-wireless now.